# Why do two nested classes in Java lead to an exception?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, nested-class

Why is java trowing a NoClassDefFoundError?

The class NestedClassTest has two nested classes, X and Y, inside.

When calling the constructor of NestedClassTest, which instantiates X and Y, java throws an exception when trying to instantiate Y.

```
public class NestedClassTest {

    private X x = null;
    private Y y = null;

    public NestedClassTest()
    {
        x = new X();
        System.out.println(x.x);
        y = new Y();
        System.out.println(y.y);
    }

    private class X
    {
        public String x = "XXX";
    }

    private class Y
    {
        public String y = "YYY";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NestedClassTest t = new NestedClassTest();

    }  
}
```

This is part of the output:

```
run:
XXX
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    Nestedclasstest/NestedClassTest$Y
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    nestedclasstest.NestedClassTest$Y
    ...
```

Comment: As-is your program works. So it's an issue with how you start it, or you have broken class files somewhere from a previous compilation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

Looking at your error you might be having troubles with incorrect packages..

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Nestedclasstest/NestedClassTest$Y
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
nestedclasstest.NestedClassTest$Y
```

nestedclasstest vs Nestedclasstest. Refer here for [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

just recompile and run again, should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that, if you are using eclipse, do a Project, Clean and try again, as the build path needs to be updated.

Comment: Follow up to this answer: If you are using Netbeans, "clean and build" is the option you'll be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is not incorrect in and of itself. You difficulties lie elsewhere, with compilation or invocation.

Answer (score -2):

You need to include the `NestedClassTest$Y` class in the classpath.